# Get a list of bean type without being mapped in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, list

I don't know if this is even possible in hibernate.

Can I get a list of a bean type (which hasn't been mapped) with the getSession() of Hibernate?

What I'm trying to do is get two values from a query. Those values are from differents tables. I have done my query but when I try to execute the getSession, it says that my Class is not Mapped.
I don't map it becasue there is no table to be mapped. I created a class named as ObjetivoAdapter which contains two Strings (The information i need to put into a list).
Also I created the class because I need a list of my information.

Those are the tables from which I get the information:

Table: producto.
Column: descripcion.
Column: codigo_barras

Table: objetivo.
Column: codigo_barras_objetivo (FK with codigo_barras from table producto).
Column: promocion_id (FK with id from table promocion)

Table: promocion
Column: id

This is my class bean ObjetivoAdapter:

```
public class ObjetivoAdapter {

    private String nombreProducto;
    private String codigoBarrasObjetivo;

    public void ObjetivoAdapter(String nombreProducto, String codigoBarrasObjetivo) {
        this.nombreProducto = nombreProducto;
        this.codigoBarrasObjetivo = codigoBarrasObjetivo;
    }

    public String getCodigoBarrasObjetivo() {
        return codigoBarrasObjetivo;
    }

    public void setCodigoBarrasObjetivo(String codigoBarrasObjetivo) {
        this.codigoBarrasObjetivo = codigoBarrasObjetivo;
    }

    public String getNombreProducto() {
        return nombreProducto;
    }

    public void setNombreProducto(String nombreProducto) {
        this.nombreProducto = nombreProducto;
    }

}
```

And this is my query:

```
public List<ObjetivoAdapter> getInfo(String codBarras) {
        String sql = "SELECT o.codigo_barras_objetivo, p.descripcion_corta FROM objetivo o "
                + "INNER JOIN producto p ON o.codigo_barras_objetivo = p.codigo_barras "
                + "INNER JOIN promocion pr ON o.promocion_id = pr.id "
                + "WHERE codigo_barras = ' " + codBarras + "';";
        List<ObjetivoAdapter> listaOA = getSession().createSQLQuery(sql).addEntity(ObjetivoAdapter.class).list();
        return listaOA;
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `setResultTransformer(AliasToBeanResultTransformer)` instead of `addEntity()` and all should be fine

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm getting the same error: {org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -1

Comment: Change dialect or check for SQLQuery.addScalar() to force Hibernate to map your database type to a well known Hibernate type. I think Hibernate.STRING will be fine. Or you can apply a cast() in your sql. If those solutions don't solve your problem, you have to debug a bit

Comment: It worked with addScalar but now says that the result cannot be casted java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl cannot be cast to java.util.List   anyway the question is answered with addScalar.